# Parse.com JSON import throws: invalid type for key ..., expected date, but got string

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

I use the [Parse.com](https://parse.com) Cloud service in my Android app to sync data between devices.

Now when I import data from a JSON file I get the error

> Row 1 is invalid: invalid type for key "updateTime", expected date, but got string

for the following data

```
"updateTime":"2016-01-14T06:15:59.6447849-03:00"
```

but it works for just the same date for the build-in Parse fields `createdAt` and `updatedAt`.

I also tried specifying the type like this

```
"updateTime": {"__type":"Date",""updateTime"":"2016-01-14T06:15:59.6447849-03:00"}
```

but that threw another error.

Since I cannot influence the import process - I need to tweak my file to make it happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does SimpleDateFormat.parse accept an invalid date string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735102/why-does-simpledateformat-parse-accept-an-invalid-date-string)

Comment: I can't influence the import process - only the file I provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this format

```
"updateTime": {
       "__type":"Date",
       "iso":"2016-01-14T06:15:59.644Z"
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me, searched for days for this type o f answer. Thank you, @juergend